# Can I restart a torrent in Vuze?

Tags: windows-7, vuze

When downloading a torrent with Vuze, files might get corrupted (transfer errors, disk issues, etc.) Is there any way to quickly restart a torrent download from scratch in Vuze, without having to manually  delete its data and restart the torrent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. it does have to be restarted by deleting the data especially if there are errors like you described occuring.

Comment: Sorry that this is probably not the answer you wanted to hear.

Answer (score 0):

right click and select the icon with two arrows rotating (force recheck) [image].

It will appear in downloading section, then right click and the play button (Queue)
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).